# how to get ${THISDIR} inside do_unpack_append in .bbappend file

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I'm attempting to replace a file from another layer with a .bbappend file.  My goal is to overwrite a specific configuration file with a customized one during the *unpack* stage.

In my .bbappend I'm attempting to append the `do_unpack` to copy a file from the same directory as the .bbappend file into the working directory  `${WORKDIR}`  The problem is: When inside `do_unpack_append`, `${THISDIR}` is returning the directory of the original .bb recipe, rather than the directory of .bbappend

Here's an example:

- The original recipe resides in: *meta-origLayer/recipe.bb*
- My *.bbappend resides in: *meta-newLayer/recipe.bbappend*

**recipe.bbappend**:

```
`FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}:"`
do_unpack_append(){
    bb.build.exec_func('replace_file', d)
}

replace_file(){
    cp -f ${THISDIR}/fileToBeReplaced ${WORKDIR}/fileToBeReplaced
    echo ${THISDIR} > ${WORKDIR}/shouldContain_meta-newLayer
}
```

There are two issues with recipe.bbappend:

1. I would expect the file *shouldContain_meta-newLayer* to contain `meta-newLayer`, but instead it contains `meta-origLayer`.
   **I'd primarily like to understand why `${THISDIR}` behaves differently when placed inside `do_unpack_append()` from when it is used for prepending `FILESEXTRAPATHS`**
2. When running bitbake, the recipe fails, producing the following error:

> cp: cannot stat '/fileToBeReplaced': No such file or directory

- This error occurs because *fileToBeReplaced* resides in a subdirectory of `meta-origLayer` (i.e. *meta-origLayer/machine1/fileToBeReplaced*) and the .bbappend expects to find the file in */fileToBeReplaced*

## My Question. . .

I have assumed `${THISDIR}` would behave consistently within the same .bbappend, but it doesn't appear to.  What is the best way to reference *meta-newLayer/fileToBeReplaced* from within `do_unpack_append()`?

Comment: `${THISDIR}` is only stable during parse time. You need to immediately-assign it to another variable outside tasks, like `THISDIRSAVED := "${THISDIR}"`. The "correct" (?) way is to add your file to `SRC_URI` (use `_append`/`_prepend`, possibly including your machine, target-os or distribution, whatever is most appropriate,  like `_append_supercomputer = " work-on-1petabyte.patch"`). That way, your file's checkum can be analyzed and added to the tasks, so if the input file changes, yocto knows when to reexecute `do_unpack`. In do_unpack, you could then replace whatever file you want.

Comment: So it turns out I was missing two major components: `SRC_URI_append` and the saved copy of  `${THISDIR}` being the second.  I was thinking that since the parent recipe already included SRC_URI for `fileToBeReplaced` I didn't need to add it again in the *.bbappend (as you point out, a rebuild isn't properly triggered if `SRC_URI` isn't present in the bbappend).  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *.bbappend correctly overwrites `fileToBeReplaced` in the working directory during the unpack task:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}:"
SRC_URI_append += " file://fileToBeReplaced "
SAVED_DIR := "${THISDIR}"

do_unpack_append(){
    bb.build.exec_func('replace_file', d)
}

replace_file(){
    cp -f ${SAVED_DIR}/fileToBeReplaced ${WORKDIR}/fileToBeReplaced
}
```

Thanks for the explanation between bbappend parsing and execution [johannes-schaub-ltb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34509/johannes-schaub-litb)